# Python - Sort list of filepaths like Windows

Tags: python, windows, sorting, filepath

I'm currently working on trying to sort a list of string file paths in the same manor as Windows Explorer does. I've been looking at several natural/human sorting algorithms that have been posted (especially ones in the natsort package) but all of them have the same problem.

Given a directory containing files "0.jpg", "00.jpg" and "000.jpg", Windows will sort them in order of decreasing precision, that is: 000.jpg, 00.jpg. 0.jpg.

All of the algorithms I've tried will sort them in the opposite order. I'm not sure how to get the desired behavior. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sort => Invert? Windows will sort whichever way you choose, depending on whether that column is sorted in ascending or descending order...

Comment: Hey i don't know it might be very late, but i have added an answer with natsort which can do this job

Answer (score 2):

This should work but it's a bit clunky:

- Determine the longest file name in the list
- Right-pad all file names to the length of the longest name with a high-value character that doesn't appear in any of the file names (such as '~') inserting it before the file extension
- Sort as normal
- Remove the inserted character before displaying the results

So

```
0.jpg, 00.jpg, 000.jpg, 1.jpg
```

becomes:

```
0~~.jpg, 00~.jpg, 000.jpg, 1~~.jpg
```

when sorted:

```
000.jpg, 00~.jpg, 0~~.jpg, 1~~.jpg
```

and finally:

```
000.jpg, 00.jpg, 0.jpg, 1.jpg
```

Comment: I ended up doing this, but instead of "~", I used chr(65535).

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I found another edge case that get introduced with this method.

Answer (score 2):

`natsort` python package can actually help in your case

```
from natsort import os_sorted
a = ["0.jpg","00.jpg","000.jpg"]
print(os_sorted(a))
```

Output:

```
['000.jpg', '00.jpg', '0.jpg']
```